# Auto Incrementing JS Object Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I am a little stumped and am probably overlooking something.
Basically I have an JS object array:

```
var defaults = {
    pointers : {
        pointer1 : {
            top : '0px',
            left : '75px',
        },
        pointer2 : {
            top : '310px',
            left : '170px',
        },
        pointer3 : {
            top : '50px',
            left : '80px'
        },
        pointer4 : {
            top : '0px',
            left : '130px',
        },
        pointer5 : {
            top : '310px',
            left : '205px',
        },
        pointer6 : {
            top : '50px',
            left : '90px'
        }
    }
};
```

If I call them manually to add to a `<li>` with class `pointer-circle` **it works fine**:

```
$('.pointer-circle:eq(1)').css({
    top : defaults.pointers.pointer1.top,
    left : defaults.pointers.pointer1.left
});
```

But instead of manually outputting each pointer want them to go through for loop:

```
var i = 1;
for (i in defaults.pointers) {
    $('.pointer-circle:eq(' + i + ')').css({
        top : defaults.pointers.pointer[i].top,
        left : defaults.pointers.pointer[i].left
    });
}
```

This does not work. In the console log I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pointer1' of undefined

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. This is what happens when I stare at the same code too long. Not sure why I got downvoted though. Just asking for help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you're going for :

```
var counter = 0;
for (i in defaults.pointers) {
    $('.pointer-circle:eq(' + counter + ')').css({
        top : defaults.pointers[i].top,
        left : defaults.pointers[i].left
    });
    counter++;
}
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wwq5tmuh/2/))

Comment: Honestly, I rewrote it a few times so initially it had been the number of `<li>`, using `$('.pointer-circle').length` with a regular for loop. So now it ends up being not what I want it to be.

Comment: @PlatinumJay : I just updated my code & posted a link to a working Fiddle.

Comment: @JohnSlegers thanks, makes sense now. I had changed my mind throughout the code that I ended up mixing myself up.

Answer (score 2):

`i` refers directly to the object. You want just `i.top`. You are conflating a standard `for` loop with a `for-in` loop. Of course, this means that `$('.pointer-circle:eq(' + i + ')')` is **not what you think it is**.